# Link to an excel sheet saved server

Tags: hyperref

I am trying to put a link of an excel sheet saved in server in my Beamer presentation.  I have used href as below

`\href{file:////Z/Documents & Papers/Ground Support/Calculation-Tool-R2.0-9.6.16.xlsx}{Ground Pressure}`

The above is not working.  Is there a way to link the file.

Comment: Technically, this is more of an HTML question than a LaTeX question.

Answer (score 1):

used `\href{run:Z/Documents & Papers/Ground Support/Calculation-Tool-R2.0-9.6.16.xlsx}{Ground Pressure}` and it is working.

Thanks.